# Quiz question -> The following program has a problem. What is it?

Tags: javascript

**The following program has a problem. What is it?**

```
var a;
var b = (a = 3) ? true: false
```

- The condition in the ternary is using the assignment operator.   <<<<----Correct ?
- You can't define a variable without initializing it.
- You can't use a ternary in the right-hand side of an assignment operator.
- The code is using the deprecated var keyword

I am not sure that the code has any problems to run.
Code looks good, and JavaScript Engine is able to understand it I guess.

However, I think the condition in the ternary is using the assignment operator. is close to the correct answer because the others can not be the answer.

Guys, please any ideas or explanation what the answer can be?

Comment: Apart of using an assignment operation, it's absolutely fine

Comment: why not run the code and check what the value of `a` is?

Comment: @AlonEitan I'd argue that even if the assignment is corrected, it's not "fine". It's meaningless.

Comment: Yes it should be `(a == 3)` or `(a === 3)`

Comment: well yes, but maybe it's the same as assigning something in a `while` loop - I'm not sure I completely understand the actual issue in the question

Comment: given the fragment in the question, why would you test for a==3 (or a===3), given the fact that the code never assigned a value to a, it could never be 3 ... therefore (a=3) or (a==3) are all equally wrong - the code should either be `var a=3, b=true;` or `var a, b=false;` (if the issue was using = instead of ===) none of those reasons given accurately describe the whole "problem" of the given code

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct, the code is using the assignment operator rather than conditional